# How to use setDefaultsOnInsert properly

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Am trying to upsert an object with a query below:

```
    await Property.findOneAndUpdate({ "property_id": property_id }, object,{ upsert: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true })
```

My schema looks like below:

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const propertySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      property_id: String,
      details: {
        location: {
          type: {
            type: String,
            default: "Point"
          },
          coordinates: [Number],
          address: String,
          country: {
            type: String,
            default: 'USA'
          },
          state: {
            type: String,
            default: 'CA'
          },
          city: {
            type: String,
            default: 'N/A'
          },
        },
        status: {
          type: String,
          enum: ['pending', 'active', 'deleted', 'suspended'],
          default: 'pending'
        },
      }
    },
    {
        strict: false 
    });
    
    propertySchema.index({ "details.location.coordinates": "2dsphere" });
    
    mongoose.model('Property', propertySchema);
    
    module.exports = mongoose.model('Property');
```

Yet, when new objects are inserted, attributes and their default values are not inserted, what am doing wrong ?

Comment: Please add `new: true,` to `{options}`, and post a result `console.log` of your query.

Comment: and also, are you sure that you are inserting `object`? What if you trying to insert `Mongoose Document` (which looks like object, but actually it doesn't) ?

Have you tried `await Property.findOneAndUpdate({ "property_id": property_id }, object.toObject(),{ upsert: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true })` ?

Comment: yup, seems I was just inserting the JSON, not a document object, thx

Comment: I had to do  `new Property(object)` instead of just `object`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a big difference between MongooseDocument and Object:

- on MongooseDocument you could apply [any method](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/document.html), like `$set` or `.save()` it. So you could modify the DB value directly. (Or convert it to JSON/Object/String and lose this property)
- when you are dealing with `JSON` or vanilla js `Object` you are modifying the object itself, not the DB value. So if you want to modify the DB document you should find it by object's key and update it.

When you are dealing with `Model.method_name`, especially with `find(One)AndUpdate` [you should provide `object` type](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate). **NOT MongooseDocument** or anything else. In that case you should convert DB doc `toObject` by [this](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/document.html#document_Document-toObject) method.

Or, if you receiving DB value via any `.find` method, you receive `MongooseDocument` by default, and you should use `lean()` option right after your find query. If you need js-object for any `findAndUpdate` method later.

For example:

```
let mongoose_doc = await model.findByID(id) //returns mongoose doc
```

but

```
let js_object = await model.findByID(id).lean() //returns you js object
```

Comment: Thank you for this piece of informations. I read the mongoose docs more than once and missed that lean() method purpose.